# How to edit location of each vertex in uv map and it's related vertex in 3d view?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to blender scripting so don't judge me If my question is stupid.
I'm trying to make a script for blender 2.79 or 2.83 doesn't matter.
The whole idea that I want to make a script for is that I want to have access to all uv vertices and their related vertex in the 3d view.
To be exact, I want to get and set the location of each uv vertex and it's 3d view vertex.
How can I get access to it and How can I set them to a different value?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's often not about judging that a question is "stupid", more often about the _seemingly_ lack of effort to seek answers before asking.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was that I tried my best and searched the whole day for it but couldn't find something. anyways thank you.